# How to filter entities that are deleted using linq to entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a singleton DBContext but for some reason when the instance is shared across 2 methods does not populate the changes made in other method.

Eg: `Method1Delete2RowS()` will delete 2 rows.
`Method2()` reads all rows that are not deleted

My method 2 always shows deleted records too. Cause i have not accepted any changes yet.

I used something like this

```
context.Students.Where(x => context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(x)
                            .State != System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
```

but this code throws an exception that "GetObjectStateEntry()" cannot be recognized by LINQ.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have `context.SaveChanges()` after deleting rows?

Comment: I dont want to save changes so i did not have that. Changes will be saved when user clicks on save

Comment: I made some change to my query as follows:

context.Students.Where(x => x.EntityState != System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
I got the followin exception
The specified type member 'EntityState' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: Is your `DBContext` really a `DbContext` or an `ObjectContext`?

Comment: it is an ObjectContext

Comment: My problem is exact same as described here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085921/get-entityframework-added-entities-as-gridview-datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is caused by the fact that EF tries to translate your LINQ query into SQL that's executed by the database. Of course there is no way to send the `GetObjectStateEntry` call to the database. You'll have to switch to linq-to-objects:

```
context.Students.AsEnumerable().Where(x => ...
```

Unfortunately in the `ObjectContext` API there's not an easy way to get undeleted entities.
In the `DbContext` API you can work with local collections, like

```
context.Students.Local
```

The local collection shows entities that were loaded by previous queries. The nice thing is that deleted entries are excluded from the local collection. Maybe an incentive for you to move to `DbContext`?

Comment: I may consider that but will spend sometime fixing this with ObjectContext

Comment: Changing to `DbContext` may take considerable refactoring, I know by experience. But it really is worth the effort. Some more incentives [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781018.aspx).

Comment: I am not able to change it. how do i do that?

Comment: See [this walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx).

Comment: Gert Arnold: I did all refactoring but after changing from ObjectContext to DbContext all my Linq stopped working. What could be wrong? I cant use First() or any other Linq methods

Comment: Ahh, that's bad, but hard to tell from here what's wrong. "Stopped working" can be anything. An exception message would help. Or else ask a new question so you can give some more details.