# Linq not working after moving from ObjectContext to DbContext EF 5

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a project where i was working with object context earlier. Now for taking advantage of reading in memory data that is not saved into db yet I had to change my ObjectContext to DbContext as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252606/how-to-filter-entities-that-are-deleted-using-linq-to-entities/20253394?noredirect=1#comment30435740_20253394)

But after the refactoring to DbContext my LinqQueries doesn't work at all.
Before:
With objectContext

```
var student1 = myContext.Students.First(); //No errors and Students is ObjectSet<Student> collection
```

After Change to DbContext but with the same code:

```
    var student1 = myContext.Students.First(); //Error: There is no method called First() on DbSet<Student>....
```

What could be the issue? and how can i resolved this

Comment: Can you please post some of your `DbContext` code?

Comment: What kind of code you want me to post? Cause there is  a lot of auto generated code

Comment: Is it just that `using System.Linq` is missing? (First excluding the obvious).

Comment: I did add ref to that. There is no change except that objectcontext is now DbContext

Comment: Are the context + POCO classes in a regular class library project? And where do you call the code snippet? And which .Net version?

Comment: Yes my context and poco are in lib project. .NET 4.5 Code snippet??